# Unable to configure SSL for Kafka Connect REST API

Tags: rest, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to configure SSL for Kafka Connect REST API (2.11-2.1.0).

**The problem**

I tried two configurations (worker config):

- with `listeners.https.` prefix

```
listeners=https://localhost:9000
listeners.https.ssl.keystore.location=/mypath/keystore.jks
listeners.https.ssl.keystore.password=mypassword
listeners.https.ssl.key.password=mypassword
```

- and without `listeners.https.` prefix

```
listeners=https://localhost:9000
ssl.keystore.location=/mypath/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=mypassword
ssl.key.password=mypassword
```

Both configurations starts OK, and show following exception when trying to connect to https://localhost:9000 :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

In log, I see that SslContextFactory was created  with any keystore, but with ciphers:

```
210824 ssl.SslContextFactory:350 DEBUG: Selected Protocols [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1] of [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
210824 ssl.SslContextFactory:351 DEBUG: Selected Ciphers   [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, ...]
210824 component.AbstractLifeCycle:177 DEBUG: STARTED @10431ms SslContextFactory@42f8285e[provider=null,keyStore=null,trustStore=null]
```

#### What I did

As I know that password from keystore is absolutely correct, I digged into source code, and started to debug.

Finally, I find out that neither plain `ssl.*` nor prefixed `listeners.https.ssl.*` configurations are not taken into account, and it turns that there is not possibility to configure SSL for Kafka Connect REST API currently.

Call sequence is:

1. [RestServer.createConnector](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.0/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/rest/RestServer.java#L146)
2. [SSLUtils.createSslContextFactory](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.0/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/rest/util/SSLUtils.java#L48)
3. [AbstractConfig.valuesWithPrefixAllOrNothing](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/config/AbstractConfig.java#L244)

Last method is the reason of troubles.

If we have `listeners.https.` properties, they cannot be returned, because they filtered out at line 254 (since WorkerConfig contains no properties with the prefix).

Otherwise, if we have unprefixed `ssl.` properties, they also not returned, because `values` field contains only known properties from the same WorkerConfig (`values` are result of [ConfigDef.parse](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef.java#L454)).

Am I missing something, and has anyone successfully configured SSL for kafka connect rest api ?

Comment: did you try adding "ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=" keep property blank.

Comment: @suraj_fale sure, but it even do not reach certificate exchange phase. It fails at cipher negotiation stage.

Comment: @Eugene did you ever get this working? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @SledgeHammer no. But I didnt test fresher versions

Comment: Moved from answer - https://github.com/sudar-path/kc-rest-mtls

Answer (score -1):

Try export `KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/apps/kafka/conf/kafka/kf_jaas.conf` where `kf_jaas.conf` contains ZooKeeper client authentication

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is unrelated to my question. My connector works ok, connects to broker without any problem. My goal is to secure built-in Kafka Connect REST API.

Answer (score -3):

I haven't test  Connect REST API, but KafkaTemplate send and recieves messages with ssl.
From your configuration i may assume two problems:

- you not specified the truststore (for certificate chain check)
- you used absolute path, but spring keystore-location interprets as
  relative to /webapp

I tried test application from examples:
https://memorynotfound.com/spring-kafka-and-spring-boot-configuration-example/
and
https://gist.github.com/itzg/e3ebfd7aec220bf0522e23a65b1296c8

Tested with springboot 2.0.4.RELEASE, used kafka library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and this my application.properties content:

```
spring.application.name=my-stream-app
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9093
spring.kafka.ssl.truststore-location=kafka.server.truststore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.truststore-password=123456 
spring.kafka.ssl.keystore-location=kafka.server.keystore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.keystore-password=123456 
spring.kafka.ssl.key-password=123456
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SSL

spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=properties test-consumer-group        
app.topic.foo=test
```

fragment of kafka server configuration:

```
listeners=SSL://localhost:9093

ssl.truststore.location=/home/legioner/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=123456
ssl.keystore.location=/home/legioner/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=123456
ssl.key.password=123456
```